# Can ulimit on containers within docker daemon process be higher than the limit of the daemon process itself?

Tags: docker, containers

Can ulimit on containers within docker daemon process be higher than the limit of the daemon process itself?

Docker documentation does not mention anything about this:

From : https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#default-ulimit-settings

> --default-ulimit allows you to set the default ulimit options to use for all containers. It takes the same options as --ulimit for docker
>   run. If these defaults are not set, ulimit settings will be inherited,
>   if not set on docker run, from the Docker daemon. Any --ulimit options
>   passed to docker run will overwrite these defaults.

Comment: Im looking for the same answer. In my case its the ECS Optimised AMI that im using. It has a `unlimit -n` set to `1024`. I can set a high number for the containers. But im not sure if the container will ever be able to use the higher limit

Answer (score 3):

I've checked with Amazon Linux and it looks like it can.

Let's check it via adjusting ulimit for max number of opened files:

1. Max number of opened file limits of the docker daemon:

```sh
cat /proc/$(ps -A | grep dockerd | awk '{print $1}')/limits | grep "files"
```

If the docker daemon is running, the output is:

```
Max open files            65536                65536                files
```

2. Now run a docker container with adjusted ulimits (let it be python, but be sure another python does not run on your machine):

```sh
# run container in daemon mode
docker run -d -it --rm --ulimit nofile=99999:99999 python python;
# show max files for the python process
cat /proc/$(ps -A | grep python | awk '{print $1}')/limits | grep "files"
```

The output:

```
Max open files            99999                99999                files
```

Comment: You have not demonstrated what you think you have demonstrated.  The only way to see for certain the limits applying to a particular process is via `/proc/<pid>/limits`.

Comment: @womble you are right, I've changed it